# Unable to send data to emulator from java through sockets

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-emulator

I run a service in android where i have a (server)socket and it listens to port 5587.I have a java (client)socket program which has to send data to the android emulator.But it cant send data to the emulator.I gave the ip address of the (server)i.e android emulator as 10.0.2.15.I also tried 10.0.0.3,10.0.0.4,10.0.0.5,10.0.0.6.But (client) java cant send data..it shows "connection timed out".My code is working fine if I give my phone ip address and run it on phone.I guess the ip address or port number is wrong.

My java program:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("enter data to send to android");
    mess = sc.nextLine();

    try {

            client = new Socket("10.0.2.15", 5587);
            // emulator ip
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            oos.writeObject(mess);
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            message = (String) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("Message: " + message);
            if(message == "Received"){

                 System.out.println("Message Sent Sucessfully");

            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Message Not Sent...Try to resend");
            }
            //close resources
            ois.close();
            oos.close();
            client.close();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

My android code is also running perfect and it waits for the client
so below i post the code which is run by a new Thread inside the service

```
 public void run() {

    try {

        server = new ServerSocket(port);// port = 5587 and ServerSocket intialised before itself

        while (true) {

            System.out.println("Waiting for client request");

            Socket socket = server.accept();
            //read from socket to ObjectInputStream object
            ObjectInputStream ois = new    ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            //convert ObjectInputStream object to String
        String message = (String) ois.readObject();

            Log.d("sri","Message Received: " + message);
               } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: i have added the code but the other parts of code are running well.i doubt about the emulator ip and port